# How to get values from my data base and feed them in a string array

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am designing a to-do app in android I've made a login system and according to that, I want that the users who create the todos go to my database and gets stored there.

I am willing to get everything on the cloud so as to make it accessible from anywhere. Kindly guide me for this project because I am new to databases.
(I have my recyclerView just need to know the method to get everything in a string array)

Comment: How about reading a tutorial? SO is for specific programming questions, not for asking how to implement something from the scratch.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to connect the Application to Android Built-in Database Consider the Given Example Code,[SQLite Demo Application](https://www.journaldev.com/9438/android-sqlite-database-example-tutorial). You can go through it, it's simple example.Then You can Perform Queries over the Database.